# Value2 Variable Not Defined

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have converted a range to an array and then I want to loop through each value to count how many no empty values there are.

For some reason this was working fine

```
Option Explicit
Sub ArrayCount ()

Dim cmArray As Variant

Set cmArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H19:CN19")

ColCount = 1

For Each Value2 in cmArray
    If Value2 <> "" Then
    ColCount = ColCount + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It all seemed simple enough to me and worked well. Now all of a sudden I am getting an error saying "Compile Error: Variable not defined" and it is highlighting Value2. Is anyone able to explain what is happening here or talk me through what may have happened?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After playing around a bit more after BK201 provided his suggestion I have found this solution.

    For Each cmArray In cmArray
        If cmArray.Value2 <> "" Then
        ColCount = ColCount + 1
        End If
    Next

Rather than testing for Value2 it seems the default of the array is value2. For some reason I can then use the cmArray.Value2 without causing a declaration error.

I don't know why it didn't work in the first place or why it works now so I won't take it as the 'answer' :) If anyone cares to explain though that would be great.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to put the Value property of a Range object in an array and loop through that array. That's not what you're doing and there are a few concepts at play here.

**Default Properties**

When you reference an object and don't specify a property, you are actually accessing its default property. For most objects, if it has a Value property, that's the default. And if it has an Item property, that's the default. The Range object is a little weird. Most times the Value property is the default property of a Range. In some cases, the Cells property is the default.  If you say

```
vValue = rMyRange
```

You are setting vValue equal to the Value property. Make it a habit to always include a property rather than rely on the default.

```
vValue = rMyRange.Value
```

**The Set Keyword**

The Set keyword stinks. But because of default properties, it is necessary. When you use Set, you're saying you want an object variable to point to an object.  If you don't use Set, you're saying you want a data variable to be equal to a value.

```
vValue = rMyRange 'vValue = rMyRange.Value
Set vValue = rMyRange 'vValue points to the range object
vValue = rMyRange.Value 'same as the first, good programming practice
Set vValue = rMyRange.Value 'you get an error - a good reason to specify property
```

**Variants**

Excel has a Variant data type that can be cast into any of the normal data types. This is because Excel cells can hold a lot of different types of data and they needed something with similar flexibility. If you want to read the value of a cell and can't be sure what will be in it, use a Variant. There are a few other times to use a Variant (like reading a range into an array). In general, don't use a Variant unless you have a very specific (and good) reason to.

**Arrays from Cells**

If you assign the Value or Value2 property of a Range to a Variant variable, and the Range has more than one cell, the variable will be cast as a two-dimensional array. It's the most awesome way to read Excel data and work with it - speed wise. But you have to start with a Variant so you have to be extra careful about the above concepts.

```
vVariant = rRange.Value 'creates an array in vVariant
Set vVariant = rRange.Value 'causes an error
Set vVariant = rRange 'vVariant gets cast to a Range object - not what you wanted
```

So use the first syntax. Then you can use `For i = LBound(vVariant,1) to UBound(vVariant,1)` to loop through. Or you can use `For Each vItm in vVariant`.

**Worksheet Function Way**

```
Sub ArrayCount()

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim lColCnt As Long

    Set rRow = Sheet1.Range("H19:CN19")

    lColCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rRow)

    Debug.Print lColCnt

End Sub
```

**Array Way**

```
Sub ArrayCntArray()

    Dim cmArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lColCnt As Long

    cmArray = Sheet1.Range("H19:CN19").Value

    For i = LBound(cmArray, 2) To UBound(cmArray, 2)
        If Len(cmArray(1, i)) > 0 Then
            lColCnt = lColCnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print lColCnt

End Sub
```

**Range Object Way**

```
Sub ArrayCountRange()

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColCnt As Long

    Set rRow = Sheet1.Range("H19:CN19")

    For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
        If Len(rCell.Value2) > 0 Then
            lColCnt = lColCnt + 1
        End If
    Next rCell

    Debug.Print lColCnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Option Explicit`, which means all variables should be dimensioned. Simply adding `Dim Value2 as Variant` at the dimension area should be enough.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ArrayCount ()

Dim cmArray As Variant
Dim Value2 As Variant
'Code follows...
```

As a side note, `Value2`, while I don't know if it's a reserved keyword, is a property. Try changing it to something else as well to be safe or to avoid confusion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi BK201 Thanks for your input. I was under the impression that value2 was an object of the array. I can view value2 in the locals window in VBA once I have set the array...I'll try your suggestion though and see if anything changes. I am still learning VBA so appreciate your help.

Comment: @JayKilleen: No worries, mate. Just remember to avoid common pitfalls like naming your variables the same as a property (`Dim Range As Range`, lol) or forgetting to declare when you have `Option Explicit`. And don't remove Option Explicit until you learn more VBA. It's a good practice. Anyway, if this was helpful, kindly accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark above. This is our way of saying thanks in Stack Overflow. :)